# Windows with putty via USB serial cable to Linux serial port - output ok, input isn't

Tags: windows, linux, putty, serial-port

I am trying to get two way serial communications going between a Windows XP system and a Linux system (RHEL 5).  I have

```
/sbin/agetty -L 9600 ttyS0
```

in /etc/inittab.

I am using a generic USB to serial adaptor on Windows (Unitek) and a null modem cable.

I have putty configured for 9600 baud, 8 bits, no parity, one stop bit, no flow control.

I get the login prompt from agetty in the putty window but input does not work; I see weird characters in the putty screen. I can echo output into the device from windows and see it, but

```
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

just prints out weird characters from what I type.

Any and all suggestions will be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a cable issue. I was using a null-modem cable and a straight-through cable was needed.  I did some testing using two USB-to-serial converters on the Linux box so that I wouldn't have windows in the picture and was able to isolate it to the serial cable.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the hardware is working ok? I would suggest opening a serial terminal program on each side and send text each way (hyperterminal on windows, minicom on linux).

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is your case, but in the past I used the same cable to connect a laptop to some working machines. Didn't work ... whatever we did, it didn't work. The cable was ok though.
Then we tried a different brand of cable (everything else, the same) ... worked!

Never found out what was wrong ... but heard from other people having the same problem.
*This is not very helpful, just saying ...*

Comment: *"... try another cable."*  yup, not the greatest explanation of *why* it happens, but sometimes it works.